# How to find the function $f(x) = [x]^2-[x^2]$ is discontinuous at all integers except $1$......

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits, continuity, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Problem :

How to find the function $f(x) = [x]^2-[x^2]$ is discontinuous at all integers except 1. where $[\hspace{2pt}\cdot\hspace{2pt}]$ represents the greatest integer function.

My approach : let $x = n \in Z$

Left hand limit : Let h is very approx. 0

$\lim_{h \to 0^+} [n+h]^2-[(n+h)^2]$

$\lim_{ h\to 0^+} n^2-n^2 = 0$

Now how to proceed further please suggest will be of great help , thanks.

Comment: For $n\in\mathbb Z$ you have to consider the possibility that $n<0.$ This has different results than you get here even for $h\to0^+.$

Comment: For reference, the graph of $f(x)$ looks like this: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%3D(floor(x))%5E2-floor(x%5E2) -- there are distinct behaviors for $n<0,$ $n=0,$ and $n>0.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe
$$[3.1^2]-[3.1]^2=9-9=0.$$
$$[2.9^2]-[2.9]^2=8-4=4.$$

You can generalize from this example, replacing $3\pm0.1$ by $n\pm h$ with $n>0$ and $h$ small enough that $(n\pm h)^2$ doesn't differ from $n^2$ by more than one.

It is an easy matter to show that the RHS are always $0$ and $2n-2$.

For negative $n$, the situation is different because the floor of a negative is the negative of the ceiling.

$$[(-3.1)^2]-[-3.1]^2=9-16=-7.$$
$$[(-2.9)^2]-[-2.9]^2=8-9=-1.$$

The RHS are $2n-1$ and $-1$.

Finally, for $n=0$,

$$[0.1^2]-[0.1]^2=0-0=0.$$
$$[(-0.1)^2]-[-0.1]^2=0-1=-1.$$

Comment: The case $n<0$ works differently.

Comment: @DavidK: you are right, thanks for raising this. I am updating.

Comment: Looks fine. At this moment I think this is the only complete and correct answer. Nobody else seems to care about negative numbers.

Comment: @DavidK: I didn't imagine a different behavior until you told me. This said, I guess that one first tries a general strategy to solve, then takes care of the details such as signs, or not. In this case, I was probably blinded by the squares.

Answer (score 4):

For h tending zero from above, we have a limit of zero as shown in your attempt.

For h tending to zero from below we get $lim_{h→0^-}[n+h]^2 = lim_{h→0^-}(n-1)^2 = n^2 -2n +1$ and $lim_{h→0^-}[(n+h)^2] = lim_{h→0^-}[n^2 +2hn +h^2] = n^2 -1$ for sufficiently small h. Thus  $lim_{h→0^-}[n+h]^2-[(n+h)^2]= 2-2n.$

These two limits differ form $n \neq 1$. Thus $f(x)$ discontinuous at all integers except 1.

Comment: The case $n<0$ works differently.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the function $f$ near integers is a good idea, but you didn't put much effort into this, have you?

So, here are your next steps:

1. Take some values of $x$ and actually calculate the function. Specifically, look for values around integers, let's say, $2$. Look at $f(1.5), f(1.8), f(1.9), f(2), f(2.1)$. What happens around $2$?
2. Now, take some other integer, say, $10$. Look at $f(9.8), f(9.9), f(10), f(10.1)$?

After looking at the values for a while, you should notice a pattern. Once you have that, you will be able to make a **general** plan of how you can prove the original statement. First do it in an informal way, but then go through the steps again and try to make them more rigorous.